# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I am trying to return a Pandas with Date that has been set as the DateTimeIndex. I have tried many things similar to

```
inx=OutputDataSet.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime()
```

or

```
inx=OutputDataSet.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime(format =''%y-%m-%d'')
```

But I keep getting the error

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DatetimeIndex'
```

This is what the info attribute is showing;

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1047 entries, 2017-01-03 to 2021-02-19
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Open         1047 non-null float64
High         1047 non-null float64
Low          1047 non-null float64
Close        1047 non-null float64
Adj Close    1047 non-null float64
Volume       1047 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 57.3 KB
```

So clearly there is a `DatetimeIndex`

The print output has no problem displaying the  `DatetimeIndex`

```
                     Open       High   ...     Adj Close   Volume
Date                               ...                       
2017-01-03   2.870000   2.940000   ...      2.842312   146804
2017-01-04   2.950000   3.090000   ...      2.871415   292371
2017-01-05   3.000000   3.000000   ...      2.871415   186374
2017-01-06   2.950000   2.970000   ...      2.764707   141723
2017-01-09   2.900000   2.970000   ...      2.842312    60815
```

Ideally I would like the DataFrame to present as

```
    Date         1047 non-null datetime
    Open         1047 non-null float64
    High         1047 non-null float64
    Low          1047 non-null float64
    Close        1047 non-null float64
    Adj Close    1047 non-null float64
    Volume       1047 non-null int64
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `DatetimeIndex` is the type of index you have on your pandas.DataFrame. Every `DataFrame` comes with the property `index` and `index` could be of different types from `DateTimeIndex` to `PeriodIndex` and `TimedeltaIndex` ([guide here](https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-time-series-examples-datetimeindex-periodindex-and-timedeltaindex))

So in your output, `Date` IS your index. You might want to rethink using pandas DataFrame if that's not the output you are expecting.

Comment: The package that I am calling is returning the DataFrame and the target system that is processing the data (SQL Server) is expecting a DataFrame to no getting away from Pandas.

Comment: Then `df.index` should return the date you're looking for. Working with Pandas is really easy, don't get me wrong. My point was, perhaps read the docs and see how you can get what you want out of it.

Comment: Got it - thank you Rikki. DateTimeIndex is an 'type' of 'property' index.

Comment: Precisely. So you could set `df.index` to `df['timestamp']` or just call `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` which will reset your index to default (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Please accept the answer when you get a chance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is the following;

```
OutputDataSet.insert(loc=0,column=''Date'', value=pd.to_datetime(OutputDataSet.index))
```

Answer (score 0):

If OutputDataSet is your dataFrame, you should call DatetimeIndex as a method in pandas and not the dataFrame.
You will want to call pd.DatetimeIndex and not OutputDataSet.DatetimeIndex.
Same to to_pydatetime. It should be pd.to_pydatetime